# Server Side Adaptive Images on the Fly

Tags: java, adaptive-design

I am writing an image server for a web project that will handle all image requests. The idea is that one image of a max resolution (for examples sake lets say 3000X2000) will be stored in the file system. When an image request comes from the client, the appropriate file will be found, then resized to match the clients dimensions and returned to the browser. To break it down:

1. File requested from client and caught by catch all servlet
2. Screen dimensions have already been stored in client cookie.
3. Max file is found on the file system.
4. Image is resized to match users dimensions.
5. Buffered image is returned to the browser. Never saved.

This of course is just an idea. It saves me from having to save 5 different image sizes for every image that is used on the project, but is this a realistic approach? Is this being used in production by any major sites? At scale if thousands of requests are coming in, will this cause memory problems? The memory should be freed as soon as the file is returned to the browser correct?

The file will be returned to the browser:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", out);
out.close();
```

Some testing using just the basic Java resize tools is showing speeds in the milliseconds, so in theory its possible, but it will of course take longer than having the resized images pre-stored. Maybe being able to serve images that are exactly the right dimensions for the requested screen size will negate the slightly slower image request?

```
private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage original, int width, int height, int type) {
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
    Graphics2D g = resized.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resized;
}
```

Comment: The most important question is: "why do you want to do this?" There might be a compelling reason, but what is it?

Comment: So that I can manage only one image rather than having to save 5 different copies at lower resolutions for each possible screen size.

Comment: You can send the resized image through HTTP by generating your own headers, etc. Also, do a benchmark to see how long it takes to fulfill a resize request. Resizing big images is sloooooow.

Comment: That's why I thought of having a max image size of somewhere around 3000 px wide. Hopefully big enough to accommodate any request and then shrink as necessary. Server side is seems to resizing an image from 3000 to 300 takes only milliseconds.

Comment: That being said, when I double to original file size to say 6000 pixels wide, it greatly increases the resize time...to around 13 seconds, which would be unacceptable. So the trick will be determining the best max resolution.

Comment: @ryandlf. The best thing you can do is run some benchmarks on different input and output size. Check this out for advice on the mechanics of sending it to the browser: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17096.html

Comment: That looks like a huge waste of memory and CPU to me. Hard disks are cheap. And there's something missing in your reasoning: you wonder if the memory will be released. You've measured the time it takes to resize one image. But you've not computed what it would cost to serve, for example 40 requests in parallel. Let's say one image resizing takes 300 ms., and needs 30 MBs of memory. Let's say you have 4 CPU cores and 40 threads to handle your 40 requests. Each image will thus take more than 3 seconds to resize, and you'll need 1200 MBs of memory.

Comment: Compare this with simply streaming 40 small image files to the response output streams: that shouldn't take more than 80 MBs of mremory, will consume almost 0 CPU, and will need to read far fewer bytes from the disk.

Comment: These guys are doing something like this but in php -- http://adaptive-images.com/  I take it they are storing and caching the new image so generation is done once.